# how do we make a request to the sendgrid API using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to make a request to the sendgrid API using kotlin. Here's what I have so far:

```
    var rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            textView.text = "Response: %s".format(response.toString())
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
    )
    rq.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

I can't seem to figure out where to put the authorization bearer token. Also the code can't find Listener and ErrorListener. I'm trying to make a request to add email contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an Android SendGrid library using Sendgrid's v3 Api. 
I'm not sure what youre trying to achieve with "adding email contact", is there an api endpoint for that?

I'm maintaining the library so if you have a request just create an Issue on Github!

https://github.com/Jakebreen/android-sendgrid